# Проблема с атрибутами при работе с XML

Tags: xml, golang

Имеется XML-документ следующего содержания:

```xml
<shop>
  <name>MyName</name>
  <offers>
    <offer id="12" available="true">
      <price>35490</price>
      <oldprice>36990</oldprice>
      <categoryId>1</categoryId>
      <name>phone1</name>
    </offer>
    <offer id="13" available="true">
      <price>45490</price>
      <oldprice>46990</oldprice>
      <categoryId>1</categoryId>
      <name>phone2</name>
    </offer>
  </offers>
</shop>
```

Необходимо достать следующие параметры:

```
id
categoryId
name
price
```

Для этого использую следующие структуры:

```golang
type OfferAttr struct {
    Id          int         `xml:"id,attr"`
}

type Offer struct {
    Id          OfferAttr   `xml:"offers>offer"`
    СategoryId  int         `xml:"offers>offer>categoryId"`
    Name        string      `xml:"offers>offer>name"`
    Price       int         `xml:"offers>offer>price"`
}
```

Ссылка на [код](https://play.golang.org/p/Xrh3mic55fz) (просто черновик, проверка работоспособности, не судите строго). В итоге получаю ошибку:

```
field "Id" with tag "offers>offer" conflicts with field "СategoryId" with tag "offers>offer>categoryId"
```

Если убрать строку

```golang
Id          OfferAttr   `xml:"offers>offer"`
```

все работает. Если убрать строки

```golang
СategoryId  int         `xml:"offers>offer>categoryId"`
Name        string      `xml:"offers>offer>name"`
Price       int         `xml:"offers>offer>price"`
```

также все работает. В чем здесь конфликт и как его разрешить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, вложенные атрибуты не поддерживаются. Но ваш код будет работать и намного лучше выглядеть, если вы просто используете другую структуру:

```golang
type Shop struct {
    Offers []*Offer `xml:"offers>offer"`
}

type Offer struct {
    ID         int    `xml:"id,attr"`
    СategoryID int    `xml:"categoryId"`
    Name       string `xml:"name"`
    Price      int    `xml:"price"`
    OldPrice   int    `xml:"oldprice"`
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/-XmuIe6GtZV.

Заодно поправил неверное именование: `ID`, а не `Id`. См. [руководство по стилю](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#initialisms).